# Getting an error adding a new fragment to an activity in an android app

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm following the tutorial on the Android developer site ([tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)) and I'm getting this error:

> The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, DisplayMessageActivity.PlaceholderFragment)

I've done a lot of research and it seems like the problem for most people is that they have imported the wrong thing but I have imported `android.app.Fragment` which is most people's solution to this error and `DisplayMessageActivity.PlaceholderFragment` is an extension of Fragment so I think the types should match fine (I also tried replacing `new PlaceholderFragment()` with `new Fragment()` and got the same error.  I think the error is coming from this file.

Below is the code for the new activity I created with the imported files; any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    if (savedInstanceState == null){
        //ERROR IS HERE
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment{
    public PlaceholderFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_message, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `getSupportFragmentManager()` when dealing with `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `getFragmentManager()` when dealing with `android.app.Fragment`.
From your example, you should use the latter.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: Typo in your code - you put `getSupportManager` instead of `getFragmentManager`.

Comment: @SimonMarquis Thank you so much. I tried to upvote you but apparently since I'm so new I can't yet. When I get the reputation that gives me the ability to upvote I will come back and do so.

Comment: @squidwardtenticles For now, if this answer is the correct answer, simply mark it as the correct one (tick the box). You could upvote later ;)